# Issue with angular 2 component not subscribing to observable in service in due time

Tags: angular, angular2-services, rxjs5

I have a component that is supposed to retrieve data from a service.

Here is my component:

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: 'app/dashboard/useraccount/firstname/useraccount-firstname.component.html',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    pipes: [TranslatePipe]
})
export class UserAccountFirstNameComponent implements OnInit {

    currentUserAccount:Object;
    errorMessage:string;

    constructor(private userAccountService:UserAccountService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.userAccountService.getCurrentUserAccount()
            .subscribe(
                param=> this.currentUserAccount = param,
                error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
            );
    }

    updateFirstName() {
        this.userAccountService.updateFirstName(this.currentUserAccount);
    }

}
```

Here is the corresponding service:

```
@Injectable()
export class UserAccountService {

    constructor(private http:Http) {
    }

    getCurrentUserAccount():Observable<Object> {
        return this.http.get('/api/useraccount')
            .map(this.mapUserAccount)
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    updateFirstName(currentUserAccount) {
        this.http.patch('/api/useraccount/firstname/' + currentUserAccount.firstName, null);
    }

    private mapUserAccount(res:Response) {
        console.log(res.json());
        return res.json();
    }

    private handleError(error:any) {
        // In a real world app, we might use a remote logging infrastructure
        let errMsg = error.message || 'Server error';
        console.error(errMsg); // log to console instead
        return Observable.throw(errMsg);
    }
```

Here is how the provider for the `UserAccountService`:

```
bootstrap(MainComponent, [ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
    HTTP_PROVIDERS,
    TRANSLATE_PROVIDERS,
    SessionService,
    UserAccountService,
    TranslateService,
    provide(RequestOptions, {useClass: ApplicationRequestOptions}),
    provide(LocationStrategy, { useClass: HashLocationStrategy }),
    provide(TranslateLoader, {
        useFactory: (http:Http) => new TranslateStaticLoader(http, 'assets/i18n', '.json'),
        deps: [Http]
    })]);
```

Here is the relevant part from the template:

```
<input type="text"
       ngControl="firstName"
       #firstName="ngForm"
       required
       minlength="2"
       maxlength="35"
       pattern_="FIRST_NAME_PATTERN"
       [(ngModel)]="currentUserAccount.firstName"
       placeholder="{{'FIRST_NAME_FORM.NEW_FIRST_NAME'| translate }}"
       class="form-control"/>
```

The issue is that by the time the template is rendered, `currentUserAccount` is still `undefined` in ngModel...

Can anyone please help?

P.S. I am puzzled as my use case (having a component calling a service method that uses http) is very similar to the angular sample provided here: http://plnkr.co/edit/DRoadzrAketh3g0dskpO?p=preview

Comment: It's hard to tell, but it seems like you are not calling `updateFirstName` anytime after instantiating. Also, it needs to be handled asynchronously. The same way you did with `ngOnInit`. If that isn't it let, me know.

Comment: + `updateFirstName` in your service is not return anything.

Comment: `updateFirstName` is irrelevant here. It is `userAccountService.getCurrentUserAccount` that is relevant.

Comment: I should probably have not included updateFirstName here in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular resolves bindings already before `ngOnInit()`. You you just invoke the async call to the server to fetch the data, which will arrive eventually (and execute the callback you passed to `this.userAccountService.getCurrentUserAccount().subscribe(...)`

To avoid an error when `currentUserAccount` is still `null` when Angular binds the view you can use the Elvis or safe navigation operator `?.` for parent-to-view binding `[]` but not for event-to-parent binding `()` this isn't supported (there are discussions to add support for this) You can use this more verbose style though:

```ts
<input type="text"
       ngControl="firstName"
       #firstName="ngForm"
       required
       minlength="2"
       maxlength="35"
       pattern_="FIRST_NAME_PATTERN"
       [ngModel]="currentUserAccount?.firstName"
       (ngModelChange)="currentUserAccount ? currentUserAccount.firstName = $event : null"
       placeholder="{{'FIRST_NAME_FORM.NEW_FIRST_NAME'| translate }}"
       class="form-control"/>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Günter. I wonder if there is a way to have resolves as with the ng 1.x router?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know Ng1 well, especially not the router. What does it do?

Comment: It resolves promises (or observables) before the route is rendered. Maybe something like implementing `OnActivate` could help...

Comment: See: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/OnActivate-interface.html

Comment: I see. Thanks for the info. `OnActivate` is supposed to allow that, but there is an open issue that it doesn't wait for the promise to resolve AFAIK. A simple workaround is to add `*ngIf="currentUserAccout"` to the outermost element in your view.

Comment: But `*ngIf`will just **not** display the view? Or wait for the observable to become available?

Comment: At first the view is not rendered. When then `currentUserAccount` changes from `undefined` (or `null`) to some value, the view is rendered.

Comment: Wow! I was not aware of this feature of `*ngIf`.

Comment: That's just Angulars change detection and JavaScripts truthiness rules. You can also write `*ngIf="currentUserAccount !== undefined && currentUserAccount !== null"`